# Chrome thinks my website is in Norwegian

Tags: google-chrome

It happened after I updated my Chrome from version 27 to 28/29. Chrome thinks my website is in Norwegian, but no, I don't understand Norwegian, my computer system setting is in English. In fact, I tested the web app on multiple computers, Chrome does the same thing to it.

The project that we are working on is a .NET MVC web app. It is rather big. I tried to traced back in SVN but failed to pin point where this issue appears. I searched around google, saw people had similar issues but they don't seem to have an answer, neither.

Anyone here happened to know the cause of this problem? Please help?

Comment: please provide a link or such, nobody can really help you otherwise.

Comment: Sorry, but I can't expose my company project link to public. I also can't repeat this issue in a simple test project. So you see I am stuck.

Comment: It's funny that the language abbreviation for Norwegian is "no", I have to think that somewhere someone was trying to say the english word no (or none and IIS cut it off after two characters.)

Answer (score 4):

Check the http header, you should have this:

```
Content-Language: en
```

Check the html tag, you should have this:

```
<html lang="en">
```

Comment: Exactly this info can also be in the URL.

Comment: There is also Content-Language in the http headers.  Is that set?

Comment: Yeah! that fixed the problem! Thanks MarkisT. Please update ur answer post. It is strange tho. I already said lang="en" why do I need to repeat content-language="en" again?

Comment: I bet that Chrome reads the Content-Language first and if it exists, it ignores the html lang.